# Does "trial" collocate with the verbs "win" and "lose": can you "win/lose a trial"?

Tags: word-choice, collocation

I know that "case" collocates with the verbs "win" and "lose".
But do these verbs also collocate with the noun "trial"? Are the phrases "win/lose a trial" and "win/lose a case" synonyms?

Comment: From a British perspective, my feeling is that win/lose do not collocate as readily with *trial* as they do with *case*. The latter is more often used with civil law cases, where guilt and innocence are not at stake, but usually questions of responsibility, damages etc involving large sums of money. A *trial* involves the criminal law, and though it is a *case*, it is not always described as such. And at *trial* one talks more of the *findings* of the jury as to whether the accused is guilty or not-guilty. It would seem unusual to hear a lawyer saying they had *won (or lost) the trial*.

Comment: "Putting aside why the Navy did what it did, did Darwin commit a failure of performance sufficient for it to **lose a trial** as to termination for default? Did Darwin have a sufficient excuse to **win a trial** as to termination for default?" https://books.google.com/books?id=XAE9AQAAIAAJ&q=%22win+a+trial%22+OR+%22lose+a+trial%22&dq=%22win+a+trial%22+OR+%22lose+a+trial%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RALzVKfWEcaUuATRioH4Bg&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA

Comment: "Jones plans to appeal that ruling, and her lawyers suggested the high court's new decision will help **win a trial**." Newsweek Vol. 132, 1998 https://books.google.com/books?id=EGLuAAAAMAAJ&q=%22win+a+trial%22+OR+%22lose+a+trial%22&dq=%22win+a+trial%22+OR+%22lose+a+trial%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RALzVKfWEcaUuATRioH4Bg&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ

Comment: "The only way to **win a trial**, according to Gulliver, is to bribe the opponent's attorney or to make one's cause appear unjust in order to 'bespeak the favour of the Bench'(p.296)." Beth Swan, *Fictions of Law,* 1997 https://books.google.com/books?id=ws5AAQAAIAAJ&q=%22win+a+trial%22+OR+%22lose+a+trial%22&dq=%22win+a+trial%22+OR+%22lose+a+trial%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RALzVKfWEcaUuATRioH4Bg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAw

Comment: "For example, the heightened burden of proof and the right against self-incrimination are both designed to make it tougher for a criminal defendant to **lose a trial** than for a civil defendant." The Cr. Law Qly. https://books.google.com/books?id=_RJKAQAAIAAJ&q=%22win+a+trial%22+OR+%22lose+a+trial%22&dq=%22win+a+trial%22+OR+%22lose+a+trial%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RALzVKfWEcaUuATRioH4Bg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case and trial have  related meanings with reference to a legal context.  Case is a more general term that refers  to a legal action that can be taken against someone, while trial refers specifically to the legal proceeding regarding a case.

[Case](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/case)  Law:

> - An action or a suit or just grounds for an action.
> - The facts or evidence offered in support of a claim.

[Trial](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trial) Law;

> - A proceeding in which opposing parties in a dispute present evidence and make arguments on the application of the law before a judge or jury: The case is expected to go to trial.
> - An instance of such a proceeding: the trial of Socrates.

Lose or win a case or a trial may be used to refer to the same facts with legal relevance.  Case, as a more general term, is more common  and has shown in Ngram it appears more frequently.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lose%20a%20trial%2Close%20a%20case%2C%20win%20a%20case%2C%20win%20a%20trial&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Close%20a%20trial%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Close%20a%20case%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwin%20a%20case%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwin%20a%20trial%3B%2Cc0): lose/win a case vs lose/win a trial:

> - I knew I wasn't the first lawyer, or the last, **to lose a trial**. It happens every court date. But always silently. Without comment. Without sharing. Ours is not a profession to openly discuss one's failings— to talk about losing. I seemed doomed to my ...
> - She said some advocates **can win a case** on cross-examination by being astute and awake and asking good questions on cross-examination. Bowers made a plea to “be kind to the trees” and pay close attention to the number of pages ...

Comment: I note you do not make any distinction between cases involving questions of guilt or innocence, and matters to settle disputes as to e.g. property etc. The OED is not much help as it has no 20th century examples. But the ODO seems to confirm my impression, for which I would be glad to be corrected if wrong, that *trial* tends to be confined to criminal cases or to determine such matters as libel. In run of the mill civil cases the court proceedings are more usually called *hearings*. I believe that to be the position in Britain, but someone please correct me if wrong.

Comment: Trial Legal Definition:
The resolution of a dispute by examination of evidence submitted by opposing litigants by a tribunal or Court of law, and determination of (1) guilt (in a criminal trial) or (2) of a civil dispute of fact or law.http://www.duhaime.org/LegalDictionary/T/Trial.aspx

Comment: Criminal trial: 

The Old Bailey in London (in 1808) was the venue for more than 100,000 criminal trials between 1674 and 1834.
A criminal trial is designed to resolve accusations brought (usually by a government) against a person accused of a crime. In common law systems, most criminal defendants are entitled to a trial held before a jury. Because the state is attempting to use its power to deprive the accused of life, liberty, or property, the rights of the accused afforded to criminal defendants are typically broad. The rules of criminal procedure provide rules for criminal trials.

Comment: Civil trial:
A civil trial is generally held to settle lawsuits or civil claims—non-criminal disputes. In some countries, the government can both sue and be sued in a civil capacity. The rules of civil procedure provide rules for civil trials.http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial

Comment: Trial: 
noun UK      (LEGAL PROCESS): 
the hearing of statements and showing of objects, etc. in a law court to judge if a person is guilty of a crime or to decide a case or a legal matter. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/trial

Comment: I am aware of the distinction between criminal and civil process. But your final link doesn't tell us much. The ODO definition is *a formal examination of evidence by a judge, typically before a jury, in order to decide guilt in a case of criminal or civil proceedings*. This seems to restrict *trial* to cases involving determination of guilt. Whilst technically I do not believe there is such a restriction, my point is that in the UK, for everyday purposes, they will not usually talk of such a process as a *trial* but as a *hearing*.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:** In US law, you *win/lose a case* but you *win/lose **at** trial*, not *win/lose **a** trial*.

**tl;dr:** In US law, a *case* is used to describe a particular lawsuit, either criminal or civil (non-criminal).

A case can be resolved at various stages. The parties can settle, dismiss the case or proceed to a formal determination.  That determination may be reached at many different stages short of a trial. A judicial officer who presides over the case may dismiss it, rule in favor of one party or another, or provide a more complex ruling that gives partial relief to one or both sides (or any combination of the foregoing).

A *trial* is a particular method for resolving a case (and not all cases can go to trial). A trial is generally a proceeding used to determine facts, based on evidence, rather than to decide issues based solely on law in which the facts are not in dispute. A decision based on a trial may be made by a judge, by a jury, or by a combination of the two, depending on what is at issue.

The resolution of a criminal case following trial is usually in the form of a *verdict*, a decision by the jury (or sometimes a judge) as to whether the defendant is guilty or not guilty. Lawyers and clients talk about *winning/losing the case*, but generally not *winning/losing the trial*.

The resolution of a civil case that goes to jury trial is generally handled like a criminal case.  A civil case that goes to trial before a judge is usually resolved in the form of a *decision* about the facts and law that leads to a *judgement*. The decision usually contains an explanation about why the case is determined in one direction or another. Lawyers and clients may talk about *a winning/losing decision*, but generally not, *winning/losing **the** decision* or *winning/losing **the** trial*. IN both cases, if a party prevails after a trial, they might say *we won **at** trial*, or *we won **after a** trial*.

Comment: Excellent answer. In U.S. law, a case is essentially a duel between opposing hired guns—and just as in a decisive gunfight one shooter wins and the other loses, so (when there is a clear resolution to the case) one lawyer wins and the other loses. Adding to the other examples that appear in bib's final paragraph, I note that people speak of lawyers' having won cases **before** the Supreme Court, as though that venue were a sort of Colosseum for legal gladiating.

Comment: While technically correct, bib, in practice both expressions are commonly used. An attorney is more likely to say, "at trial" but "defendants" and "respondents" will often say "we lost/won the trial."